# How can I remove everything beyond this 10 character alphanumeric string with notepad++ using regex

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a long text file with some garbage data I need to clean up.

The entries are as follows.

```
American Chopper    0x4156003D  American Chopper    5849
American Chopper 2: Full Throttle   0x4156004F  American Chopper 2 Full Throttle    5849
America's Army: Rise of a Soldier   0x55530043  America’s Army:RoaS 5849
```

I need to remove everything beyond the 10 digit alphanumeric strings which begin with `0x`

The result should look like

```
American Chopper    0x4156003D
American Chopper 2: Full Throttle   0x4156004F
America's Army: Rise of a Soldier   0x55530043
```

Comment: Do the 10 characters always start with 0x?

Comment: yes, the 10 chars will always begin with `0x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find characters coming after them by doing as followed:

1. In the Find what box, enter the following formula : `(?<=0x[A-Z0-9]{8}).*`.
2. In the Replace with box, enters nothing (empty string).
3. Select Regular expression, then you can click on Replace All.

Since your string seems to always be an hex number, then you may replace the `Z` on the formula with an `F`. You can also add `a-f` to provisioned for the case there small letters. The formula will be: `(?<=0x[A-Fa-f0-9]{8}).*`

**Explanation:**`?<=0x[A-Z0-9]{8}).*` is a positive look behind that will find/match all characters that come right after the 10 alphanumeric character string.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: thank you very much for your time and help!